# Azure Durable Function - Parameter provider error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-durable-functions

While trying to build Azure Durable Function, i am getting error while trying to build my first program.

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation 'xxxxxxxx'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Unable to resolve the Azure Storage connection named 'Storage'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Failed to run function CLI command from staging folder(azure-functionsxxxxxxxxxxxx), value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider').
```

I am tryint to follow this tutorial, but to no vail : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-java?pivots=create-option-manual-setup&tabs=bash

My functions code is copied from that link.

I have my local setting as :

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your storage account connection string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}
```

Also my gradle.build as :

```
plugins {
    id "com.microsoft.azure.azurefunctions" version "1.12.0"
}
apply plugin: "java"

group 'com.phoenix.api'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.functions:azure-functions-java-library:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft:durabletask-azure-functions:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'
}
```

I dont know what is mising to create this error as I was unable to find it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figure it out.

Problem was in run configuration as InteliJ didnt use my local.setting.json file and I needed to specify connection string to storage by hand.

IntelliJ will save your config after fisrt build and wont update after changes in local.settings.json file.